# "if choice in" is saying that it is unreachable

Tags: python-3.x

```
def add(x,y): return x+y

def subtract(x,y): return x-y

def divide(x,y): return x/y

def multiply (x,y): return x*y

print("select operation.") print('1.add') print('2.subtract') print('3.divide') print('4.multiply')

while True: choice=input('Enter choice(1/2/3/4):') if choice in ('1','2','3','4'): num1=float(input("Enter first number: ")) num2=float(input("Enter second number: ")) if choice =='1': print(num1,"+", num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

elif choice =='2': print(num1,"-", num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice =='3': print(num1,"/", num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))

elif choice =='4': print(num1,"*", num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2)) 'break' else: print("invalid input")

elif choice =='2':
print(num1,"-", num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice =='3':
print(num1,"/", num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))

elif choice =='4':
print(num1,"*", num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))
'break'
else:
print("invalid input")
```

Comment: I would suggest to format your code to increase readability. Enclose your code in ``` to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Just formatted your code (Python scopes are defined with indentation, so be careful when posting your code somewhere), replaced `'break'` with `break`, added a `break` after each calculation, moved the two `else` statements to the end of their respective scope and removed the extra conditions you had duplicated. It's working fine now:

```
def add(x,y):
  return x+y

def subtract(x,y):
  return x-y

def divide(x,y):
  return x/y

def multiply (x,y):
  return x*y

print("select operation.")
print('1.add')
print('2.subtract')
print('3.divide')
print('4.multiply')

while True:
  choice=input('Enter choice(1/2/3/4):')
  
  if choice in ('1','2','3','4'):
    num1=float(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2=float(input("Enter second number: "))
  
    if choice =='1':
      print(num1,"+", num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
      break
    elif choice =='2':
      print(num1,"-", num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))
      break
    elif choice =='3':
      print(num1,"/", num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
      break
    elif choice =='4':
      print(num1,"*", num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))
      break
    else:
      print("invalid input")
  else:
    print("invalid input")
```

Output with inputs "1", "2" and "4":

```
select operation.
1.add
2.subtract
3.divide
4.multiply
Enter choice(1/2/3/4):1
Enter first number: 2
Enter second number: 4
2.0 + 4.0 = 6.0
```